# Errors using psclip and psframe

Tags: pstricks

Yesterday I've posted a question because I needed to fill a space between two curves using pspicture and I appreciate the answers. This is the post: 
[How to fill a delimited space between curves using pspicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/535874/how-to-fill-a-delimited-space-between-curves-using-pspicture/535897?noredirect=1#comment1354192_535897)
Now I tried to use the code that helped me to fill the areas in another figures like this:
[image: New figure]
But if you can see, there is a kind of rectangle at the bottom of the figure and I don't want it :( and I am pretty sure that 'rectangle' is created by the **line 46** of the code that which I will attach below, and that line contain this command `\psframe[linecolor=colour2, fillstyle=solid,  linewidth=0.02 ,linestyle=none](0.8, -1.4)(9.13, 2.928)`. How could I choose those points `(0.8, -1.4)(9.13, 2.928)` to avoid errors in this figure and other figures that I should work with? I need to fill the space in a few more figures and the second `\psframe` is causing me the errors.
This is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pst-grad}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,font=small,justification=justified]{caption}
\input{tcilatex}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(3.7,-3.762997)(10.56794,8.762997)

%COLORES
\definecolor{colour0}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,1.0} %Azul
\definecolor{colour1}{rgb}{1.0,0.0,0.2} %Rojo
\definecolor{colour2}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8} %Gris claro (linea punteada)
\definecolor{colour3}{rgb}{0.0,0.2,1.0} %Azul
\definecolor{colour4}{rgb}{0.2,0.6,0.0} %Verde
\definecolor{bubblegum}{rgb}{0.99, 0.76, 0.8}
\definecolor{bananayellow}{rgb}{1.0, 0.88, 0.21}
%Además, se usan colores:
%MidnightBlue: Curva IC
%LimeGreen: Curva PC
%Black: Ejes
%Gray: Región de soluciones

%EJES
%Vertical:
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.03,  arrowsize=0.05291666666666667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.0]{->}(0.810012,-1.6741458)(0.810012,9.125854)
%Horizontal
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.03, arrowsize=0.05291666666666667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.0]{->}(0.810012,-1.6741458)(11.110012,-1.6741458)

%SOLUCION FACTIBLE
%Region de soluciones
\psclip{
    \pscustom[linestyle=none]{
        \psline(0.810012,-1.6741458)(6.7, 8.3)
        \psline(6.7, 8.3)(0.9, 8.3)
        \psbezier(0.9, 8.3)(1, 5)(5.655, -0.8)(10.5, -1.5)
        }}
\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=colour2, opacity=0.3](0.810012,-1.6741458)(9, 8.95)
% or \psframe[fillstyle=vlines](0.810012,-1.6741458)(9,9.125854)
\endpsclip
\psframe[linecolor=colour2, fillstyle=solid,  linewidth=0.02 ,linestyle=none](0.8, -1.4)(9.13, 2.928)


%CURVAS
%Curva LLC
%Vertical
\psline[linecolor=bubblegum, linewidth=0.02, linestyle=dashed](0.835, -1.65)(0.835, 8.95)
%Horizontal
\psline[linecolor=bubblegum, linewidth=0.02, linestyle=dashed](0.84,-1.65)(10.85,-1.65)
%Curva IC
\psline[linecolor=MidnightBlue, linewidth=0.05](0.810012,-1.6741458)(6.7, 8.3)
%Curva PC
\psbezier[linecolor=LimeGreen, linewidth=0.05](0.9, 8.3)(1, 5)(5.655, -0.8)(10.5, -1.5)
%Curva Isocosto
\psline[linecolor=LimeGreen, linewidth=0.05](1.5, 4.5)(6, 1) %C*
\psline[linecolor=bananayellow, linewidth=0.05](2.5, 3.41)(6.4, 0.39)

\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](1.6, 4.42)
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](1.85, 4.22)
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](2.1, 4.02)
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](2.35, 3.82)
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](2.6, 3.62)
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](2.85, 3.43)
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](3.1, 3.25)
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](3.35, 3.05)
%mitad
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](3.68, 2.8)%9
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](3.93, 2.6)
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](4.18, 2.42)
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](4.43, 2.22)

\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](4.68, 2.03)
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](4.93, 1.83)
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](5.18, 1.65)
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](5.43, 1.46)
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](5.68, 1.26)
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](5.93, 1.06)
%Optimal Incentive S.
%\psline[linecolor=bubblegum, linewidth=0.05](3.21, 3.33)(0.8,5.2)


%TEXTO AGREGADO (Números, Letras, etc)
\rput[bl](0.73,-2.1076814){$\scriptstyle{0}$}
\rput[bl](10.93,-2.2076814){$w_{\scriptscriptstyle{F}}$}
\rput[bl](0.16,8.7){$w_{\scriptscriptstyle{E}}$}
\rput[bl](10.5, 8.2){$45^{\circ}$}

\rput[bl](0.16, 2.928){$w^{*}_{\scriptscriptstyle{E}}$}
\rput[bl](0.16, 1.9){$w^{t}_{\scriptscriptstyle{E}}$}

\rput[bl](3.35, -2.2076814){$w^{*}_{\scriptscriptstyle{F}}$}
\rput[bl](4.25, -2.2076814){$w^{t}_{\scriptscriptstyle{F}}$}

\rput[bl](1.1, 4.45){$\scriptstyle{C^{*}}$}

%INTERSECCIONES
%Línea 45 grados
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.0, linestyle=dashed, dash=0.18cm 0.11cm](0.81,-1.6741458)(10.5,8.02)

%Línea horizontal punteada de intersección UNO
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.0, linestyle=dashed, dash=0.18cm 0.11cm](0.810012, 1.93)(4.41, 1.93) 
%Línea vertical punteada de intersección UNO
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.0, linestyle=dashed, dash=0.18cm 0.11cm](4.41, -1.6741458)(4.41, 1.95)
%Interseccion UNO
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.1](4.41, 1.93)

%Línea horizontal punteada de intersección DOS
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.0, linestyle=dashed, dash=0.18cm 0.11cm](0.810012, 2.928)(3.5, 2.928) 
%Línea vertical punteada de intersección DOS
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.0, linestyle=dashed, dash=0.18cm 0.11cm](3.52, -1.6741458)(3.52, 2.93)
%Interseccion DOS
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.1](3.52, 2.928)


%LEYENDA
\psframe[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.01, fillstyle=solid, dimen=outer](16.070012,2.5)(10.110012,5.8)
%Recta mala
\psline[linecolor=bananayellow, linewidth=0.05](10.480012, 5.314146)(11.1133455, 5.314146)%1
%PC (binding)
\psline[linecolor=LimeGreen, linewidth=0.05](10.480012,4.85)(11.1133455,4.85)%2
%IC (binding)
\psline[linecolor=MidnightBlue, linewidth=0.05](10.480012,4.395854)(11.1133455,4.395854)%3
%LLC (binding)
\psline[linecolor=bubblegum, linewidth=0.05, linestyle=dashed, dash=0.13638889cm 0.10583334cm](10.480012,3.88)(11.1133455,3.88)%4
%Isocost %5
\psline[linecolor=LimeGreen, linewidth=0.05, 0.10583334cm](10.480012,3.45)(11.1133455,3.45)
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](10.52, 3.45)
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](10.80, 3.45)
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](11.08, 3.45)
%Region solutions
\pspolygon[linecolor=gray, linewidth=0.02, fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=colour2, opacity=0.3](10.4, 2.85)(11.25, 2.85)(11.25, 3.05)(10.4, 3.05)%6

%Texto
\rput[bl](11.4733574, 5.2191875){\footnotesize : Tangent Solution}%2
\rput[bl](11.4733574, 4.7191875){\footnotesize : PC (binding)}%2
\rput[bl](11.4733574, 4.2191876){\footnotesize : IC (binding)}%3
\rput[bl](11.4733574, 3.7191876){\footnotesize : LLC Manager (binding)}%4
\rput[bl](11.4733574, 3.27){\footnotesize : Isocost representing $C^{*}$}%5
\rput[bl](11.4733574, 2.8){\footnotesize : Region of feasible solutions}%6

\end{pspicture}
\end{center}

{\footnotesize \textbf{Figure 10.} Linear incentives with logarithmic utility function. }

\end{document}
```

I will appreciate any comments to learn and a possible solution for this case and recommendations for the other ones, thanks :)

Comment: Is the yellow line (with the label "Tangent Solution") supposed to be tangent to the green line (PC Binding) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code works:

```
...
%Black: Ejes
%Gray: Región de soluciones

%EJES
%Vertical:
%SOLUCION FACTIBLE
%Region de soluciones
\psclip{
    \pscustom[linestyle=none]{
        \psline(0.810012,-1.6741458)(6.7, 8.3)
        \psline(6.7, 8.3)(0.9, 8.3)
        \psbezier(0.9, 8.3)(1, 5)(5.655, -0.8)(10.5, -1.5)
        }}
\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=colour2, opacity=0.3](0.810012,-1.6741458)(9, 8.95)
% or \psframe[fillstyle=vlines](0.810012,-1.6741458)(9,9.125854)
\endpsclip
\psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=white, linestyle=none](0.8,-1.8)(9.13, 2.928)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.03,  arrowsize=0.05291666666666667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.0]{->}(0.810012,-1.6741458)(0.810012,9.125854)
%Horizontal
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.03, arrowsize=0.05291666666666667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.0]{->}(0.810012,-1.6741458)(11.110012,-1.6741458)
%CURVAS
%Curva LLC
%Vertical
%\psline[linecolor=bubblegum, linewidth=0.02, linestyle=dashed](0.835, -1.65)(0.835, 8.95)
%Horizontal
%\psline[linecolor=bubblegum, linewidth=0.02, linestyle=dashed](0.84,-1.65)(10.85,-1.65)

...
```

```
%Isocost %5
\psline[linecolor=LimeGreen, linewidth=0.05](10.480012,3.45)(11.1133455,3.45)
```

[image]

In the future, I suggest you should learn [Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/) !!