# Error filling a space using psclip and psframe

Tags: errors

Actually I'm working on a figure and I need to fill an specific part but when I do that, I have a little error. (A part that is not need to be filled, do it anyways)
This is my output:
[image]

Could anyone help me please? This is my code and I think the error is on the line 33 on the command `\psframe`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pst-grad}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,font=small,justification=justified]{caption}
\input{tcilatex}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(3.7,-3.762997)(10.56794,8.762997)

%COLORES
\definecolor{colour0}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,1.0} %Azul
\definecolor{colour1}{rgb}{1.0,0.0,0.2} %Rojo
\definecolor{colour2}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8} %Gris claro (linea punteada)
\definecolor{colour3}{rgb}{0.0,0.2,1.0} %Azul
\definecolor{colour4}{rgb}{0.2,0.6,0.0} %Verde
\definecolor{bubblegum}{rgb}{0.99, 0.76, 0.8}
\definecolor{bananayellow}{rgb}{1.0, 0.88, 0.21}

%SOLUCION FACTIBLE
%Region de soluciones
\psclip{
    \pscustom[linestyle=none]{
        \psline(4, 3.5)(4, 6) %Cota lateral
        \psline(0.84, 6)(4, 6) %Cota superior
        \psline(0.84, 6)(0.84, 2) %Cota lateral (eje)
        \psbezier(0.83, 2)(1.5, 1)(5.655, -0.2)(9.65, -0.9) %PC
        \psbezier(0.81,-0.5)(1.9,2)(5.2,4.2)(8.65,4.8) %IC
        }}
\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=colour2, opacity=0.3](0.810012,-1.6741458)(9,9)
% or \psframe[fillstyle=vlines](0.810012,-1.6741458)(8.5,6.2)
\endpsclip
\psframe[linecolor=colour2, fillstyle=solid,  linewidth=0.02, linestyle=none](0.810012,-1.6741458)(8.5, 1.22)

%EJES
%Vertical
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.03,  arrowsize=0.05291666666666667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.0]{->}(0.810012,-1.6741458)(0.810012,8.3)
%Horizontal
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.03, arrowsize=0.05291666666666667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.0]{->}(0.810012,-1.6741458)(11.110012,-1.6741458)

%CURVAS
%Curva LLC
%Vertical
\psline[linecolor=bubblegum, linewidth=0.05, linestyle=dashed](4, -1.65)(4, 7)
%Horizontal
\psline[linecolor=bubblegum, linewidth=0.05, linestyle=dashed](0.84, 6)(8.4, 6)

%Curva IC
\psbezier[linecolor=MidnightBlue, linewidth=0.05](0.81,-0.5)(1.9,2)(5.2,4.2)(8.65,4.8)
%Curva PC
\psbezier[linecolor=LimeGreen, linewidth=0.05](0.83, 2)(1.5, 1)(5.655, -0.2)(9.65, -0.9)

%Kink Solution
%\psline[linecolor=LimeGreen, linewidth=0.05](1.41, 4.15)(4.23, 1.85292143)
%Tangent Solution
\psline[linecolor=bananayellow, linewidth=0.05](2.2, 1)(4.2, 0.3)

%Curva Isocosto
%\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](1.5, 4.05)
%\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](1.95, 3.7)
%\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](2.4, 3.35)
%\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](2.85, 3.1)
%\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](3.3, 2.62)
%\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](3.75, 2.26)
%\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](4.2, 1.9)

%TEXTO AGREGADO (Números, Letras, etc)
%Horizontales
\rput[bl](1.81, -2.2076814){$w^{*}_{\scriptscriptstyle{F}}$}
\rput[bl](3, -2.2076814){$w^{t}_{\scriptscriptstyle{F}}$}
\rput[bl](3.9, -2.15){$1$}
\rput[bl](3.85, -2.45){$=$}
\rput[bl](3.8, -2.9){$Y_{F}$}

%Verticales
\rput[bl](0.38, 5.8){$2$}
\rput[bl](0.38, 1.85){$1$}
\rput[bl](0.3, -0.65){$\frac{4}{25}$}
\rput[bl](0.13, 1.1){$w^{*}_{\scriptscriptstyle{E}}$}

%Básicas
\rput[bl](10.5, 8.2){$45^{\circ}$}
\rput[bl](0.5, -2.1076814){$0$}
\rput[bl](10.8, -2.1){$w_{\scriptscriptstyle{F}}$}
\rput[bl](0.13, 8){$w_{\scriptscriptstyle{E}}$}

%INTERSECCION
%Línea 45 grados
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.0, linestyle=dashed, dash=0.18cm 0.11cm](0.81,-1.6741458)(10.5,8.02)

%Interseccion UNO
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.1](1.92, 1.22)
%Línea horizontal punteada de intersección
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.02, linestyle=dashed, dash=0.18cm 0.11cm](0.810012, 1.22)(1.92, 1.22)
%Línea vertical punteada de intersección
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.02, linestyle=dashed, dash=0.18cm 0.11cm](1.92, -1.6741458)(1.92, 1.23)

%Interseccion DOS
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.1](3.17, 0.73)
%Línea vertical punteada de intersección
\psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.02, linestyle=dashed, dash=0.18cm 0.11cm](3.17, -1.6741458)(3.17, 0.73)

%LEYENDA
\psframe[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.01, fillstyle=solid, dimen=outer](16.070012,2.5)(10.110012,5.8)
%Recta mala
\psline[linecolor=bananayellow, linewidth=0.05](10.480012, 5.314146)(11.1133455, 5.314146)%1
%PC (binding)
\psline[linecolor=LimeGreen, linewidth=0.05](10.480012,4.85)(11.1133455,4.85)%2
%IC (binding)
\psline[linecolor=MidnightBlue, linewidth=0.05](10.480012,4.395854)(11.1133455,4.395854)%3
%LLC (binding)
\psline[linecolor=bubblegum, linewidth=0.05, linestyle=dashed, dash=0.13638889cm 0.10583334cm](10.480012,3.88)(11.1133455,3.88)%4
%Isocost %5
\psline[linecolor=LimeGreen, linewidth=0.05, 0.10583334cm](10.480012,3.45)(11.1133455,3.45)
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](10.52, 3.45)
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](10.80, 3.45)
\psdots[linecolor=black,fillcolor=white, dotstyle=o, dotsize=0.15](11.08, 3.45)
%Region solutions
\pspolygon[linecolor=gray, linewidth=0.02, fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=colour2, opacity=0.3](10.4, 2.85)(11.25, 2.85)(11.25, 3.05)(10.4, 3.05)%6

%Texto
\rput[bl](11.4733574, 5.2191875){\footnotesize : Tangent Solution}%2
\rput[bl](11.4733574, 4.7191875){\footnotesize : PC (binding)}%2
\rput[bl](11.4733574, 4.2191876){\footnotesize : IC (binding)}%3
\rput[bl](11.4733574, 3.7191876){\footnotesize : LLC Manager (binding)}%4
\rput[bl](11.4733574, 3.27){\footnotesize : Isocost representing $C^{*}$}%5
\rput[bl](11.4733574, 2.8){\footnotesize : Region of feasible solutions}%6
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}

{\footnotesize \textbf{Figure 4.} Generalized model of incentives with risk aversion.}

\end{document}
```

I'll appreciate any suggestions, have a nice day.

Comment: What is `tcilatex`, if you don't mind?

Comment: I don't know so much but is to compile a figure that is native from Scientific WorkPlace. I've downloaded from this site: http://www.personal.soton.ac.uk/rchc/Teaching/GTPBootstrap/tcilatex.tex and I add to my folder

Comment: That explains some strange things in the code. For instance, the `epsfig` package is obsolete, and the color names are not defined (I know most of them, as they come from the `svgnames` option of `xcolor`, which is loaded by `pstricks`), but not all, e.g. `bubblegum`. I'll see what I can do

Comment: Thanks Bernard!

Comment: My code is based on a solution that a user of this site give me in this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536073/errors-using-psclip-and-psframe
The user197952 show me the way to fill the space but I do not know how to select the points (x,y) on the `\psframe`to avoid thoses errors in the output. :(